# I'd like to know the inverse of this function:$ y = 100x + 5 (x - 1) (x / 2)$

Tags: functions, inverse

I'm developing a game with a ranking system and I'm using the formula $$y = 100x + 5 (x - 1) (x / 2)$$ to figure out how much XP is needed to obtain a certain rank. Now the problem is, I also need to know what rank a player has depending on the amount of XP! Some help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try expressing y in terms of x ?   A simple quadratic simplification will do the trick

Comment: With the correct assumptions basically you can solve an equation like $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ where basically $c$ from y$

Comment: probably not the *inverse*, but the *reciprocal*. For the inverse is simply $\frac 1 {100x +5(x-1)(x/2)}$ ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve for $x$ given $y$, notice that
$$
y = 100x + 5(x-1)(x/2)
  = 100x + 2.5x^2 - 2.5x
  = 2.5x^2 + 97.5x
$$
so given $y$ you have
$$
2.5x^2 + 97.5x - y = 0
$$
and apply the [Quadratic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Comment: This did the trick, thanks.